# iphone - UIImagePickerController... making it appear from the right

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have to present a UIImagePickerController but when I do so, it always come from the bottom up. Is there a way to make it appear from the right to left?

I have tried this without success:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.35f;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are currently displaying the picker by calling presentModalViewController:animated: and passing YES as the animated option.

What you can do instead is present without animating, and instead cover the appearance using your own transition animation. The example below would present from the right:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:NO];
```

To use this you'll need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add the QuartzCore framework to the project.

Comment: Sorry there was an extra block of code that I meant to remove that shouldn't have been there. Update to the new version, and If it's still coming from the bottom, are you sure you set the animated parameter to NO?

Comment: yes. I have noticed that block and ignored. It is still coming from the bottom.

Comment: I've just tried this and it definitely works. Did you copy it exactly - the version in your question is different. For example you need to apply the animation to self.view.window.layer, not self.navigationController.view.layer, and you should present it on a regular view controller, not on a navigation controller.