# Presenting UIimagepickercontroller from popover with transition from right

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a root UIViewController showing photos (on a UINavigationController) displayed on a PopOverController in ipad.
   
 I have a rightBarButtonItem on my root UIViewController which evokes a UIImagePickerController. I am able to display the PickerController in my PopOver Size by `cameraViewCtrl.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;`

But it always appears from bottom, I am looking to present it from right to left like native navigation push transition style. I have referred this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861561/iphone-uiimagepickercontroller-making-it-appear-from-the-right)  .This is not the solution because it move the entire window from right and not just the PopOver's UIImagePickerController.

Is it due to UIModalTransitionStyle is UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical by default and I don't want a flip transition by UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal.

Is there any alternate way out to present a UIImagePickerController in a navigational transition way from  right to left style?

Comment: Please check this [Transition of view controllers - from left to right][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631653/transition-of-view-controllers-from-left-to-right

Comment: Well the animation with that takes place but UIImagePicker is not displayed. Just a blank view of that vc is shown.